# How to set reminder for a task with recurring due date in todoist?

Tags: reminder, todoist

Is there a way to set reminders based on a recurring due date?

In the case of a task with an annual task with due date "ev 23 Apr", I have been able to set a reminder "ev 20 Apr 10:00" to ensure I get a reminder 3 days before the due date at 10am. But that's an annual task and I've had to calculate the reminder offset manually.

How would I get a reminder at 10am 3 days ahead of a task with due date "ev 6 months from 30 Jul"?

NB: I tried "due -3 days 10:00" but "due" was ignored and it interpreted it as "3 days before today at 10am starting next year"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes... *but only if your due date also has a due time.***

1. Add a due time to your six-monthly task: "ev 6 months from 30 Jul **10:00**".
2. Now select the Reminders icon. Because you have added a time to the due date, a new option will appear "Before task". Select this.
3. You'll be presented with a list of options. Select "3 days before".

### Notes

- If you want your reminder to be at 10:00, your due time must be 10:00. Not ideal, but a small compromise to get the feature.
- If you wanted your reminder to be "5 days before", you can't do this at present, because that isn't one of the options and this isn't currently a free text field.

See also [Todoist Help: Reminders](https://support.todoist.com/hc/en-us/articles/205348301-Reminders)

*Thanks to David Trey at Todoist support for providing the answer via email.*

Comment: I wish this limitation has been removed from Todoist because there is a big disadvantage of due time in Todoist... This is changing the order of the tasks displayed in Today view. In the vast majority of my use cases, I don't want my tasks to be at the top of the list just because they have a due time. And one of the great thing about reminders is that they don't affect the order.